# Perform a left join deduplicating based on second column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have two dataframes that for now we can think as:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name1=c("SAN LUIS",rep("SAN JORGE",3),rep("CARMEN",2)),
              code_ins = c(428,rep(746,3), rep(555,2)),
              code_est=c(1,rep(2,3),rep(3,2)),
              quantity = c(10:15))

df2 <- data.frame(name1=c(rep("CARMEN",2),rep("SAN JORGE",2),"SAN CARLOS"),
              code_ins = c(rep(555,2),rep(746,2),323),
              code_est=c(7,3,2,5,3))
```

I need to "left_join" or "append" df2 to df1, so I did:

`df_joined <- left_join(df1,df2,by="code_ins")`

Now, my problem is that I don't want the SAN JORGE AND CARMEN duplicated, cuz there is information to deduplicate them: the column code_est.
So basically, what I need is a left_join based on code_ins, but whenever there is more than one match, I need to tell R to look for a match in the column code_est.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
df_joined <- left_join(df1,df2,by=c("code_ins","name1"))
```

Comment: Nope, you still get the same duplicated rows.. I need like a secondary criteria in case of "ties"

Comment: your solution relies on the join criteria.. I need a hierarchy of criteria

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to do...